# Setup of SQLServer 2008 want to reboot

Tags: windows-vista, windows-registry

I want to setup a sqlserver 2008 developeredition on my windows-vista notebook but the setup-check want me to reboot first. But this doesn't help after reboot the setup want a reboot again.

I got the tip: You can open Regedit, and modify this key"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet?\Control\Session Manager" and delete any value in "PendingFileRenameOperations?"

That works for one try, later i have the same strange entries in this particular registry-Key. What could reenter this values?

```
\??\C:\Windows\TEMP\logishrd\LVPrcInj03.dll

\??\C:\Windows\TEMP\logishrd\
```

Edit: The Question is: how come these entry after a reboot again in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had an issue before with some Microsoft software (can't remember off the top of my head what it was) which choked with a similar *You need to reboot* message because there was stuff in the RunOnce registry keys - I don't know about SQL Server, but it's worth a shot.

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Comment: i checked only the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet?\Control\Session Manager" and deleted any values in "PendingFileRenameOperations?" and all worked fine (allmoust). The Answers is: how come these entry after a reboot again in there?